# Returning reference to trait rather than struct

Tags: rust

I'm running into an issue trying to return a reference to a trait in Rust. I can return a reference to a struct OK.

This is a contrived example to reproduce the problem, but I have a `Person` struct defined as:

```
struct PersonStruct<'a> {
    age: u32,
    photo: Option<PhotoStruct<'a>>
}
```

I have a `Person` trait too, and I am trying to write a method on this trait to return a `Photo` trait, rather than a `PhotoStruct`.

The full source is below, but the issue is that this method works fine:

```
    fn get_photo_struct(&'a self) -> Option<&'a PhotoStruct<'a>> {
        let photo_ref = self.photo.as_ref();
        photo_ref
    }
```

... and this one won't compile ...

```
    fn get_photo_trait(&'a self) -> Option<&'a Photo<'a>> {
        let photo_ref = self.photo.as_ref();
        photo_ref
    }
```

The difference is, the first returns the struct and the second returns the trait. There is an implementation of the trait for the struct.

The compilation error is:

```
src/lib.rs:40:9: 40:18 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::option::Option<&'a Photo<'a> + 'a>`,
    found `core::option::Option<&PhotoStruct<'_>>`
(expected trait Photo,
    found struct `PhotoStruct`) [E0308]
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on what I'm doing wrong or what approach I should be taking instead.

Full source:

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::vec::Vec;

struct PhotoStruct<'a> {
    photo_bytes: &'a [u8]
}

struct PersonStruct<'a> {
    age: u32,
    photo: Option<PhotoStruct<'a>>
}

trait Photo<'a> {
    fn get_bytes(&self) -> &'a[u8];
}

impl<'a> Photo<'a> for PhotoStruct<'a> {
    fn get_bytes(&self) -> &'a[u8] {
        return self.photo_bytes;
    }
}

trait Person<'a> {
    fn get_age(&self) -> u32;
    fn get_photo_struct(&'a self) -> Option<&'a PhotoStruct<'a>>;
    fn get_photo_trait(&'a self) -> Option<&'a Photo<'a>>;
}

impl<'a> Person<'a> for PersonStruct<'a> {
    fn get_age(&self) -> u32 {
        self.age
    }
    fn get_photo_struct(&'a self) -> Option<&'a PhotoStruct<'a>> {
        let photo_ref = self.photo.as_ref();
        photo_ref
    }
    fn get_photo_trait(&'a self) -> Option<&'a Photo<'a>> {
        let photo_ref = self.photo.as_ref();
        photo_ref
    }
}
```

Comment: On side note: You usually shouldn't insert `Struct` into your type names... Just call it `Person` or `Photo`. Just a small hint on better style...

Comment: If we are commenting on style, I'd recommend dropping the `get_` prefixes and the redundant `let` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast it to a `&Photo`:

```
fn get_photo_trait(&'a self) -> Option<&'a Photo<'a>> {
    let photo_ref = self.photo.as_ref();
    photo_ref.map(|photo| photo as &Photo)
}
```